# UIImageView resize after load larger image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a `UIImageView` in IB. I set the frame and image. The point is my image is 300x193, but later i want to update a bigger image and use some `contentMode` on this View.

So on start i have:

[image][image]

So it's clear for me that frame should stay `310 116 300 193` and i want to to stay that way (that's why i use `Scale To Fill` `ContentMode`.

So i have image picker here and when i use this code:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self.imView setImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

My UIImageView frame change to:

```
(UIImageView *) $0 = 0x1c5c1ae0 <UIImageView: 0x1c5c1ae0; frame = (-160 20; 640 1136); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c5c1b40>> - (null)
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add width and height constraints to your image view. I'm not sure why you didn't get those automatically, I got them when I dragged in an image view.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is caused by auto-layout.  The layout allows the view to grow to accomodate differently sized images, so it does.  Do you have a blue "user" constraint with a >= sign in it?

Under "show file inspector" in IB, you can uncheck the "Use Autolayout" and you'll see the behavior changes to match what you want.  To leave Autolayout in effect and get the behavior you want, you may need to review each constraint and how it affects the size of that view.

Comment: Even if i uncheck autolayout effect is still the same.

Comment: Odd.  The view shouldn't be resizing on it's own.  If you don't select 'clip subviews' on the image; some modes will allow the image to draw outside the making it appear the view changed sized.  However, contentMode = 'scale to fill' shouldn't draw outside the frame.  Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce what you describe.

Comment: From Apple's UIImageView documentation: "Setting the image property does not change the size of a UIImageView. Call sizeToFit to adjust the size of the view to match the image."  Maybe start a new app project and test this behavior in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your view mode from `Scale to Fill` to `Aspect to Fit`.

Comment: But Ascpect To Fit is not behavior i want. This is not a solution for filling UIImageView.

Comment: You want the image to be stretched and/or distorted when it fills out the imageview?